# Remove bracket inside hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

My program looks like this which is defined with hash:
where $varname and $varValue are passed dynamically from the file:Below is my program:

```
$appOptk= {
%hash{$varName}=>$varValue,                                                                         
                };
push @{$hash{metrics}->{appOptions}},$appOptk;


Output of the program looks like this:

"metrics": {
            "appOptions": [{
                    "shell.common.report_default_significant_digits                ": "4"
                }, {
                    "time.remove_clock_reconvergence_pessimism                     ": "true"
                "route.detail.hop_layers_to_fix_antenna ": "true "
            }, {
                "clock_opt.flow.optimize_layers                                ": "false"
            }, {
                "clock_opt.flow.skip_placement                                 ": "true"
                }
            ],
```

Can anyone please tell how to get below output by removing brackets inside the hash

```
"metrics": {

            "appOptions": [{
        "shell.common.report_default_significant_digits             ": "4"
    "time.remove_clock_reconvergence_pessimism                    ": "true"
            "route.detail.hop_layers_to_fix_antenna ": "true "
        "clock_opt.flow.optimize_layers                           ": "false"
    "clock_opt.flow.skip_placement                                 ": "true"
            ],
```

Comment: Can you post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please? And fix the formatting, your post is hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to read if everything was in Perl. I think this is what you want.

```
$hash{metrics}{appOptions}[-1]{$varName} = $varValue;
```

Of course, you have to decide when a new array is added to the list.

```
# add new array
push @{$hash{metrics}{appOptions}}, {};
```

Answer (score 0):

your expected output doesn't make any sense to me but you can achieve it by change `push @{$hash{metrics}->{appOptions}},$appOptk;` to

```
${@{$hash{metrics}->{appOptions}}[0]->{$varName}} = $varValue;
```

Comment: m getting thois error: Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference